# Json arrays - select elements in left array that are not in right array

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

For each cust_id I have aggregated the array1 column all rows created_at after for each shape_id. Note the array1 column is json!
Now I have two json array columns (array1,array2) I want to select all elements that are in the left array (array1) but not in the right (array).

Can anyone help me?

Many thanks in advance...

I've tried the below code and am stuck on where to go. I know I could use json_array_elements and do a left join and then use json_agg to stick it back together but thinking there must be a more elegant way.

```
create table a
(cust_id numeric,shape_id numeric,array1 json,created_at timestamp with time zone);

insert into a
(cust_id,shape_id,array1,created_at)
values
(123,1,'[1,2,3]','2019-07-23 13:42:33+10'),
(456,1,'[3,4,5]','2019-07-23 13:44:52+10'),
(789,1,'[2,10,11]','2019-07-23 13:48:11+10'),
(555,2,'[5,4,3,2]','2019-07-26 13:48:11+10'),
(888,2,'[1]','2019-07-27 13:48:11+10'),
(982,3,'["x"]','2019-07-23 13:48:11+10');

SELECT a1.cust_id,
       a1.shape_id,
       a1.array1,
       a1.created_at,
       (SELECT json_agg(jae.e)
               FROM a a2
                    CROSS JOIN LATERAL json_array_elements(a2.array1) jae (e)
               WHERE a2.shape_id = a1.shape_id
                     AND a2.created_at > a1.created_at) array2
       FROM a a1;
```

Actual results:

```
cust_id  |  shape_id  | array1    | created_at              |    array2
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
123      | 1          | [1,2,3]   | 2019-07-23 13:42:33+10  | [3,4,5,2,10,11]  
456      | 1          | [3,4,5]   | 2019-07-23 13:44:52+10  | [2,10,11]    
789      | 1          | [2,10,11] | 2019-07-23 13:48:11+10  |
555      | 2          | [5,4,3,2] | 2019-07-26 13:48:11+10  | [1]
888      | 2          | [1]       | 2019-07-27 13:48:11+10  |
982      | 3          | ["x"]     | 2019-07-23 13:48:11+10  |
```

Expected results:

```
cust_id  |  shape_id  | array1    | created_at              |  
-------------------------------------------------------------
123      | 1          | [1]       | 2019-07-23 13:42:33+10  |  
456      | 1          | [3,4,5]   | 2019-07-23 13:44:52+10  |     
789      | 1          | [2,10,11] | 2019-07-23 13:48:11+10  |
555      | 2          | [5,4,3,2] | 2019-07-26 13:48:11+10  | 
888      | 2          | [1]       | 2019-07-27 13:48:11+10  |
982      | 3          | ["x"]     | 2019-07-23 13:48:11+10  |
```

Comment: If you're generating the Json by aggregation, surely it would be easiest to exclude the rows you don't want before you aggregate ?

Comment: And how would I do? You can use my code to create the table and insert the data to see how I'm aggregating it

Comment: I can't see how you're aggregating it? That's just a plain insert of some already aggregated data. I want to go back a step to the part where you generated this data, implied by your statement "For each cust_id I have aggregated the array1 column [by cust_id,shape_id]"

Comment: No the data in the insert statement is not already aggreagate. It is aggregated in the select query below the insert and the 'Actual results' is the result of that select query 8) Thanks

Comment: Ok, then I think you should go the other way; expand this data into a set of custid, shapeid, element, createddate, then reduce it (couldn't quite get your criteria; do you want the max created date and it's associated customer for a particular shape/element combination?)

Comment: I want to compare array1 and array2 on each row and remove elements any elements from array1 that is is array2. (see 'Actual results' and 'Expected results')

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT y.cust_id, y.shape_id, y.created_at, json_agg(y.value) as array1
FROM
(
   SELECT t.cust_id, t.shape_id, j.value, t.created_at,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.shape_id, j.value::text ORDER BY t.created_at DESC) as rn
   FROM 
    a t
    CROSS JOIN LATERAL json_array_elements(t.array1) j(value)
) y
WHERE y.rn = 1
GROUP BY y.cust_id, y.shape_id, y.created_at
```

It takes your data (snippet):

```
123,1,[1,2,3],2019-07-23 13:42
456,1,[3,4,5],2019-07-23 13:44
```

And expands the Json so each element in the array is a single value on its own row, duplicating all the other row data, so it becomes (expanded snippet):

```
123,1,1,2019-07-23 13:42
123,1,2,2019-07-23 13:42
123,1,3,2019-07-23 13:42
456,1,3,2019-07-23 13:44
456,1,4,2019-07-23 13:44
456,1,5,2019-07-23 13:44
```

It then reduces it by picking only the latest row as determined by numbering shape/array1_element combinations sequentially, in order of descending created_at. It then picks only those with created_at = 1. Here's the bit of the query that does that magic:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY shape_id, element ORDER BY created_at DESCENDING) as rn
  FROM <expanded_data>
) 
WHERE rn = 1
```

This will return only the newest shape/element pairing and its associated customer:

```
123,1,1,2019-07-23 13:42
123,1,2,2019-07-23 13:42
                           <--the array1_element = 3 row from 13:42 is removed because a newer one from 13:44 exists
456,1,3,2019-07-23 13:44
456,1,4,2019-07-23 13:44
456,1,5,2019-07-23 13:44
```

We then re-aggregate the elements into a Json array based on shape/customer combination

```
123,1,[1,2],  2019-07-23 13:42
456,1,[3,4,5],2019-07-23 13:44
```

Comment: So why has the [1,2,3] in your expected results for customer id 123 been reduced to just [1] then? It looks to me like the later 3 from customer 345 removed the 3 from 123 and the later 2 from customer 789 removed 123's 2 (I don't think you're taking the time to understand what I'm saying)

Comment: Because the were cust_id's on the same shape_id that have 2 and 3 as elements in array1 and they were created_at after it

Comment: That's what I'm saying, and what the query I posted does. Read the post again

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying how can your query be used with my above select query

Comment: It can't; your select query is the hard way to do it (you're aggregating all the Json after the current row and then trying to remove everything in Json array a from Json array b. I'm saying throw your query away and go the route of: expand your Json, pick the latest records, reaggregate into Json. Having gotten access to a fiddle site I've been able to edit in an example query - take a look